# SourceTree Clone - Source path with port causing not a valid source path/ URL

Tags: git, ssh, version-control, clone, sourcetree

SourceTree is a great little tool, and it's been working with one of my hosts and repositories just fine. However, i tried to set up and clone another repository from a different host and found it couldn't find it.

The path i was using is - 
user@server.net:1000/home/account/www/site/

Is this the correct way to put in a port into this? The SSH doesn't work without the specific port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, i didn't actually set a protocol. For anyone who gets stuck with this in the future, don't forget to put ssh:// at the start of your URL